# Set custom zoom in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I really searched this for many times and in many ways but didn't find an effective solution. Let's get to the point: **How can I set *custom zoom level* in *Google Chrome* besides the fixed levels??**[Here, I don't need the crossed ones, and I want to insert 115 and 120 in between the arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CuVR.png)
Thanks in advance. I have tried editing the HTML via inspect but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

if You want to zoom in chrome at your will and not by the choices given by the chrome. So, you can try this open inspect select html tag and on right in the inline style write this `transform: scale(1);` here 1 -> 100% (original) replace it with what ever you want. like 1.15 -> 115%, 1.23 -> 123%, etc.
check this
[image]

Comment: Works, but seems to confuse Chrome if the page is scrolled. If you then use Ctrl+/- and scroll up, you won't be able to see the top of the page. Anyway, cool trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome extension for Zooming (if just YOU need it).
If you want to zoom your website for everyone, use the "transform answer".
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom/lajondecmobodlejlcjllhojikagldgd/related

It won't limit you ;-)